# Need to Access Locally Hosted (Ubuntu VM) Website from Host Machine/Another Computer

Tags: server, virtualbox, apache2, localhost, wordpress

So I created a wordpress site within my Ubuntu VM and I am locally hosting it there. I have followed every tutorial I can find online to no avail so I will try to be as thorough as possible in my descriptions.

- I need to access the site from other computers on the network, so I figured I would start by being able to access it from the host machine, running Windows 10.
- I ensured my VM is running bridged rather than NAT
- In my VM, within `/etc/hosts` I changed `127.0.0.1` to `site.local` rather than `localhost`
- In my host machine's host file, I added `192.168.1.139 site.local`, where that is the IP of my VM, determined by running `ifconfig`.
- Within my `apache2` conf files, I made a few changes from solutions I found online but none of them worked, so I reverted my changes. I know that is not descriptive but I tried solutions from multiple sources so it became a bit convoluted.
- Within my VM, if I go to `site.local/wordpress` it redirects to `localhost/wordpress`. `localhost` is not defined in the `hosts` file anymore. The same goes for `127.0.0.1/wordpress` or `192.168.1.139/wordpress`. They all redirect to `localhost`.
- In my host machine, I can type `192.168.1.139` in the browser and see the Apache2 Ubuntu default page. If I type `http://site.local` I get `the requested URL [no URL] is invalid.` If I type `192.168.1.139/wordpress`, it redirects to `localhost/wordpress` and says `The site can't be reached. localhost refused to connect`.
- I gave my wordpress folder `777` permission just in case; no luck.
- My host machine can successfully ping the IP of my virtual machine
- I set up a new rule listening for a TCP connection on port 80 on my windows machine

So this is where I am currently at. I hope I have been descriptive enough. Essentially, I can connect to the VM based off of the fact that I can get to the Apache2 Ubuntu default page, but I cannot get to my wordpress site. Thank you in advance for any help; I'm really stumped on this one.

**SOLUTION FOUND:**

I realized a potential solution Friday evening as I was about to leave the office and tested it this morning. It worked. The issue was somewhere in the database it was redirecting the IP I typed in to "localhost," which when ran on another computer was trying to use that computer's localhost. By following the steps in [this article](https://wpbeaches.com/updating-wordpress-mysql-database-after-moving-to-a-new-url/) and replacing all occurrences of "localhost/wordpress" with "ip-of-vm/wordpress" it fixed the issue and worked on other computers.

Comment: Just doing a follow up. Wondering if you got this working?

Answer (score 0):

Let us know if this [online post](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/vmware/allow-access-to-a-vmware-virtual-machinenat-from-another-computer/) works for you.
Suggestion: Disable all firewalls on all machines while testing this out. After you get it working, you can setup firewall rules, re-enable firewall, and make sure it is working as desired.

Comment: Hi there, I realized a potential solution Friday evening as I was about to leave the office and tested it this morning. It worked. The issue was somewhere in the database it was redirecting the IP I typed in to "localhost," which when ran on another computer was trying to use that computer's localhost. By following the steps in [this article](https://wpbeaches.com/updating-wordpress-mysql-database-after-moving-to-a-new-url/) and replacing all occurrences of "localhost/wordpress" with "ip-of-vm/wordpress" it fixed the issue and worked on other computers. Thank you for the help though.